# visual studio.net has detected that web server is not running the asp.net 1.1 version , you will be unable to open or create web application

Tags: iis-6, visual-studio-2003, iis-5, windows-xp-sp3

the program visual studio 2003 installed on my system showing me this message when try to open the web application.

### visual studio.net has detected that web server is not running the asp.net 1.1 version , you will be unable to open or create web application

i have checked my application running on iis 5.1 web server , it is using 1.1.4322 version . Shall i need to install again the visual studio 2003  again?

Comment: Just to make sure: you are aware that .NET 1.1 is ancient? I mean it's from 12 years ago.

Comment: my project is also too old , it was made in visual 2003

Comment: It's possible to upgrade. Also, is .NET 1.1 even _supported_ any more? At least upgrade to .NET 2.0. Also, FYI, VS2013 has a free version now.

Comment: One problem with using such ancient software is that very few people remember how it worked.

Comment: finally my problem is resolved, i have tried the three things 1. reinstall iis 5.1 2. reset iis with1.1 version.3. there is also one wwwroot folder which was at the location where my visual studio commnad prompt was pointing , i have removed that folder , doing this makes me enable to create web application . 4. after that i reconfigure the binding in iis of my site and it makes me enable to open the website in visual studio 2003

Answer (score 1):

I tried the followings:

1. i removed the higher version on my system as there was conflict in iis settings.
2. i removed the iis and reinstall from the windows components including front page server extensions. reset the IIS version by using the command  cd %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
   **strong text**
3. my visual studio command prompt was pointing to c:\documents and settings/pooja.sharma . there was the same folder named wwwroot , i have removed this. and after doing this i am able to create web application
4. i corrected the binding in web server by adding new virtual directory . this makes me to open the web application in visual studio 2003